# StreamWriter is not able to write in file

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is

```
System.IO.StreamWriter objStreamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(File);
objStreamWriter.Write(txtEditor.Text);
objStreamWriter.Close();
txtEditor.Text = string.Empty;
```

I got a message `The file has been modified out side of.............` but my text file is empty.  When in debug mode, I got a value of `textEditor` and path is not a problem.  Am I missing some stupid things.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like something else is modifying your while while you have it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to verify the content of `txtEditor` before you write it to disk file.

```
string text=txtEditor.Text;
if(text.Trim.Length!=0)
{
  using(System.IO.StreamWriter objStreamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(File))
   {
       objStreamWriter.Write(text);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Its a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use the StreamWriter by the "using" keyword for correct writing in to textfile.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("important.txt"))
{
    writer.Write("Word ");
    writer.WriteLine("word 2");
    writer.WriteLine("Line");
}
```

Refer to the [C# Using StreamWriter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter) for more info